# React not rendering the view on mobile browser when fetching data from API

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I noticed something strange today when I accessed my localhost from my mobile phone that are both on same network (wifi).

The thing is the page is not being rendered on my phone and the page shows blank, while it works pretty fine on my computer.

Here is the code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './assets/css/bootstrap.min.css';
// import './assets/js/bootstrap.min';
import { Timeline, Tweet} from 'react-twitter-widgets'
import config from './config';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            mainImage: {
                url: null,
                caption: null
            },
            uuid: null,
            title: null,
            author: {
                name: null,
                email: null,
                image: null
            },
            tags: [],
            premium: null,
            preamble: null,
            body: [],
            publishingTime: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchArticle();
    }

    fetchArticle() {
        fetch(config.apiUrl + "article/f3028496-d1e6-42cb-b39a-8e9593d5a05a")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                this.setState({
                    mainImage: data.mainImage,
                    uuid: data.uuid,
                    title: data.title,
                    author: data.author,
                    tags: data.tags,
                    premium: data.premium,
                    preamble: data.preamble,
                    body: data.body,
                    publishingTime: data.publishingTime,
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };

    conditionalRendering(block, key) {
        let blockType = Object.keys(block)[0].toLowerCase() || null;
        if (blockType != null) {
            if (blockType === 'paragraph') {
                return this.renderParagraph(block, key);
            } else if (blockType === 'headline') {
                return this.renderHeadline(block, key);
            } else if (blockType === 'image') {
                return this.renderImage(block, key);
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Block type null")
        }
    }

    renderParagraph(block, key) {
        return (
            <p key={key}>{block.paragraph}</p>
        );
    }

    renderHeadline(block, key) {
        return (
            <h4 key={key}>{block.headline}</h4>
        );
    }

    renderImage(block, key) {
        return (
            <div key={key}>
                <img width="100%" src={block.image.url} alt=""/>
                <p><i>{block.image.caption}</i></p>
            </div>

        );
    }

    renderTwitterEmbeds(twitterId) {
        return (
            <Tweet
                tweetId={twitterId}
            />
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className={"container-fluid article"}>
                    <div className={"row header header"}>
                        <img width="100%" height={"260px"}
                             src={this.state.mainImage.url}
                             alt=""/>
                        {/*<p><i>{this.state.mainImage.caption}</i></p>*/}
                    </div>
                    <div className={"row"}>
                        <div className={"col-sm-12 content text-left mt-2"}>
                            <h4>{this.state.title}</h4>
                            <p>{this.state.author.name} | {this.state.publishingTime}</p>
                            <p className={"preamble mt-3"}>{this.state.preamble}</p>
                            {
                                this.state.body.map((block, key) => {
                                    return this.conditionalRendering(block, key)
                                })
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className={"row"}>
                        <div className={"col-sm-12 content text-left mt-2"}>
                            {
                                this.renderTwitterEmbeds("1099398639942856705")
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

What do you think would be the issue here that my web app is not being rendered from my phone?

Comment: do you have another computer on your network that you can perform the same request to? might be more an infra issue with how the site is being served but at least testing from another computer will allow you to view the debugger to see whats happening

Comment: unfortunatelly I dont have any other device :S

Comment: but I mean the js code looks fine as per my view.

Comment: can also try removing all logic first and just rendering a static "hello", if that can't render then it's an infra issue more than likely.Iif it shows then next best guess is how the fetch is happening (if the congif.apiUrl should be set to an ip not localhost something like that), also you show an image where on first render the data is def going to be null `this.state.mainImage.url` (shouldn't break anything major but isn't helping)

Comment: @Quince If i change any of the state and add some static string, it works fine on mobile.

Comment: ok next best guess is the fetch does not work, add an error flag to your state so you can set it in the catch and then render when there is an error as a quick way to see  i imagine thats where the cause is

Comment: also out of curiosity what is `config.url` if its 'localhost' its going to fail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189063/discussion-between-quince-and-mizlul).

Comment: @Quince confg.url is not localhost, it is some https url that is accesible by every1